# How to make editable menus with OpenCms

Tags: content-management-system, opencms

How to make editable menus with OpenCms. I want when user clicks on edit button then he can change anything with menu - menu label, Link URL, he can add/del an item from sub-menu list etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a `<cms:editable/>` tag in your JSP, so when the user un logged in, he will see the OpenCMS editable icon (blue, white and red circle). You must put the cms editable tag anywhere at the beginning of the page. Then, you mark your content tag (`<cms:include>`, `<cms:content>`, etc.) as editable, with editable atribute.

Example:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="cms" uri="http://www.opencms.org/taglib/cms" %>

(things here...)

<cms:editable/>

(more things here...)

<cms:contentload collector="allInFolderDateReleasedDesc" param="<%=url%>" editable="true">
(content html...)
</cms:contentload>

<cms:contentload collector="allInFolderDateReleasedDesc" param="<%=url2%>" editable="false">
(content html...)
</cms:contentload>
```

With this, you have one "direct editable" element, and other not editable.

Hope it helps.

P.S.: More references in http://www.vinu.edu/cms/opencms/alkacon-documentation/documentation_taglib/docu_tag_editable.html

Comment: Can u guide me what is url we have to provide, because i am not able to provide correct url value

Answer (score 0):

You should use a structured content definition (xsd) to define your page sections and it's elements, i.e. in your case it would be an embedded menu.xsd for example with label, link, etc.

In the jsp template for it, you would use  and then page will be editable, lead the user to the editor to edit the structured content.

Not sure if this short answer helps, but I don't know the status of your development and how far it's already done, if you're using structured content or not, etc.

The OpenCms docs

http://www.bng-galiza.org/opencms/opencms/alkacon-documentation/documentation_xmlcontent/

would be a good reference and starting point; although I must admit the learning curve for OpenCms is not low due to lack of beginner's tutorials/documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered but...

The best way doing customizable menus with OpenCms is to use the Navigation property of every item. With relatively simple programming you can build your menu scanning all "navigable" items in a folder. Users can just edit Navigation title and position of the menu option keeping multi-language feature.

Take a look here:
http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Example_template_with_tree_menu